# How to move code from google cloud source repositories to github enterprise along with existing versions

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, github-enterprise, google-cloud-source-repos

We have the code in GCP source repo and would like to move it GitHub Enterprise. Is there any easiest way move code from google cloud source repositories to GitHub enterprise along with the existing release versions ?

Comment: There's an existing issue for this that you can check [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/121117390) and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the following steps:

1. git remote set-url origin <target_repo>
2. git push -u origin
3. git push --tags (To push the release versions)